# Win32 debugger within Jython (like pydbg)

Tags: debugging, jython

I am a python user and like pydbg for debugging win32 applications. Recently, I started using Jython for a project. I need a win32 debugger similar to pydbg for jython, but I am surprised that my search returned no relevant results. I shall appreciate any pointer in this direction. thanks
regards
-Sanjay

Answer (score 0):

I found [this platform-independent debugger](http://winpdb.org/download/)

Hopefully this is what you were looking for. If you were looking for a different environment for your interpreter altogether, let us know.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I am not looking for a debugger to debug python programs as such. I am looking for a debugger for windows executable, which is available in Jython. As jython can import jar files, is there any debugger written in java to debug Win32 apps?